# Tomcat no more stopping down on error following Spring Boot migration

Tags: java, spring-boot

We have just migrated from Spring Boot 1.3.1 to 1.4.4 and we encounter a last problem that we have not been able to solve yet.

We use embeded tomcat in fat jar.

We perform a lot of processing at Spring Boot startup in our config classes and we were happy in 1.3.1 that tomcat was shutting down when fatal errors were thrown during this startup phase.

Now that we have migrated in 1.4.4, the embeded tomcat is not stopping any more and it complicates things for us because we have to look at log files to see if fatal errors occurred at startup.

This happens when we start the JAR with Spring Boot Maven plugin but also if we start it through Java command line.

We though that devtools could be the cause and tried to exclude it but we didn't succeed or there were not impact.

Note that we use spring-boot-starter-parent as parent for our project.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [a bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8224) that'll be fixed in 1.4.5.

Comment: Tanks for your answer.
Is there a risk to send in production an application compiled with this version knowing that in production we do not use embeded tomcat but real tomcat on which WAR are deployed ?

Comment: There's no risk. The bug is specific to Boot's support for embedded containers. The code that's affected won't be used when your app's deployed as a war to a separate container.

Comment: Thanks a lot
I hope 1.4.5 will arrive soon in release version